# How to query relationship using data from model as a condition?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have an **Employee** model, which hasOne **Position** model.
The **Position** model hasMany **salaries** model relationhip:

An employee is assigned to a "position" (eg Software developer)
A position has many salaries, depending on years of experience

The employee model has an "experience" field to indicate the years of experience

I want to retrieve the salary for this Employee, taking into account its position and years of experience

I'm trying something like:

(in my Position model):

```
public function salaryForExperienceYears($years)
  {
    return $this->hasOne(Salary::class)
                ->where('experience', $years)
                ->first()
                ->salary
                ;
  }
```

(in my controller, where I want to get the info):

```
$employee->position->salaryForExperienceYears(1);
```

if I hardcode "1" for the num of years, it works, logically.
but I want to use this employee's years of experience, and I can't do that:

```
$employee->position->salaryForExperienceYears($employee->experience);
```

How should I do it?

Even if I can get a way of doing this using this structure, it feels like there's a better way of doing it... because "experience" is already a property in $employee...

the same way I have a relationship for ->position which is "constraining" the results using the position_id field available in $employee, it feels like there should be a way where the experience field is also "inferred from context" here (although it's not a relationship in a different table)

Maybe I should be using some other type of relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$experience = $employee->experience;
$employee->position->salaryForExperienceYears($experience);
```

Comment: yes, this works, thanks. But still, feels like there should be a "more elegant" way of doing it, doesn't it? after all, you're passing a property from $employee inside a cascade call that starts, preciselly, with that $employee... somehow feels kind of redundant...

Answer (score 0):

Use leftJoin in salaryForExperienceYears:

```
public function salaryForExperienceYears()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Salary::class)
                ->where('experience', new Expression('years'))
                ->lefftJoin('employees', 'id', 'employees_id')
                ->first()
                ->salary
                ;
}
```

Or

```
$position = $employee->position;
$selary = $position->salaryForExperienceYears($employee->experience);
```